# Pin Cells to Top of UICollectionView Edge

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a horizontally scrolling `uicollectionview`. I dynamically change each cell's height based on the length of a `subview` `uilabel` text string. At the end, I set the `uicollectionview` height constraint to equal the longest cell height.

This result in a `uicollectionview` where each cell varies in height and prevents me from achieving my goal: get all cells' tops to align and be pinned to the top edge of the `uicollectionview`.

Is anyone able to lend a hand here? I understand I might have to create a custom layout for this, but have no clue where to start and could not find any references to instruct. Any guidance would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Show an image of what you are currently getting, compared to what you want to get. It sounds like you should constrain the cell's content elements to the top of the cell, and leave empty space at the bottom.

Comment: @DonMag added an image for clarity!

Comment: OK - so, make all the cells the same height and constrain their UI elements to the top of the cell's contentView - done!

Comment: @DonMag that did it for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

easy to do it with custom `UICollectionViewLayout`,

**put it simple:**

you just assign the frame of each item manually.

Notice the logic in `func prepare()`

The rest method are just common mode.

for variable item height, you can use a delegate to fetch the value.

```
enum CommonComponent: String {
  case cell
  case header
  
  var kind: String {
      switch self{
      case .header:
          return "UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader"
      default:
          return ""
      }
  }
}


protocol CustomLayoutProxy: AnyObject {
    func getHeightFor(indexPath ip: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
}



class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    
  weak var delegate: CustomLayoutProxy?
    
  override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
     CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth, height: contentHeight)
  }
  
  // MARK: - Properties

  private var contentHeight = CGFloat.zero

  private var cache = [CommonComponent: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]]()
    
    
  private var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
  
  private var collectionViewHeight: CGFloat {
     collectionView!.frame.height
  }
  
  private var collectionViewWidth: CGFloat {
     collectionView!.frame.width
  }

    let maxItemSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
}


// MARK: - LAYOUT CORE PROCESS
extension CustomLayout{
  
  override public func prepare() {
         guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
             return
         }
        
         prepareCache()
     
        var cellX: CGFloat = 16
        
        let countOne = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

         let headerIP = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
         let headH: CGFloat = 58
         let headerAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: CommonComponent.header.kind, with: headerIP)
         headerAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: contentHeight, width: UI.std.width, height: headH)
         cache[.header]?[headerIP] = headerAttributes
        
        contentHeight += headH
    
        for item in 0 ..< countOne{
              let cellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
              let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndexPath)
            
              var size = maxItemSize
              if let h = delegate?.getHeightFor(indexPath: cellIndexPath){
                  size.height = h
              }
              attributes.frame = CGRect( x: cellX, y: contentHeight, width: size.width, height: size.height )
              contentHeight += exceedUp(origin: &cellX, limit: collectionViewWidth)
              cache[.cell]?[cellIndexPath] = attributes
            
        }
        contentHeight += (maxItemSize.height + 16)
   }

    private func prepareCache() {
        contentHeight = 0
        cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        cache[.cell] = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        cache[.header] = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    }
}


//MARK: - PROVIDING ATTRIBUTES TO THE COLLECTIONVIEW
extension CustomLayout{
  
    
    public override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind ComponentKind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
          switch ComponentKind {
          case CommonComponent.header.kind:
            return cache[.header]?[indexPath]
          default:
            return nil
          }
    }
    
    override public func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
            return cache[.cell]?[indexPath]
    }

    
    override public func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
          guard let _ = collectionView else { return nil }
          visibleLayoutAttributes.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
          for (_, infos) in cache {
            for (_, attributes) in infos {
              attributes.transform = .identity
              if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                  visibleLayoutAttributes.append(attributes)
              }
            }
          }
          return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    
    func exceedUp(origin x: inout CGFloat, limit widthX: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        var exceedH: CGFloat = 0
        let lineSpacing: CGFloat = 20
        let interitemSpacing: CGFloat = 16
        let contentEdge = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
        if x + maxItemSize.width * 2 + interitemSpacing + contentEdge.right < widthX + 1{
            x += maxItemSize.width + interitemSpacing
       }
       else{
           x = contentEdge.left
           exceedH = (maxItemSize.height + lineSpacing)
       }
       return exceedH
    }
}
```

For more example , you can check my github repo

- [BoxDengJZ/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout](https://github.com/BoxDengJZ/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout)
- [coyingcat/CardCollection](https://github.com/coyingcat/CardCollection)